# Swift: how to display bold words in textview without attributed string

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

We're adding the finishing touches to an app we're working on, and that apparently means putting an entire "Terms and Conditions" and "FAQs" section, formatting, bullets, breaks and all.

So I tried copy-pasting it into a textView with "editable" set to off, which kept the bullets, but not the bolded text.

Now, I've done attributed string before, and I have to say, I'm not sure it will be easy to do that on some 12-pages worth of paragraphs, bulleted lists and breaks that are likely to change in a few years or so.

So my question is, is there a way to do this without using attributed string?

Barring that, perhaps there's a way to loop through the text, and look for a written tag that will apply the attributes?

EDIT:

Update. It's been suggested I use HTML tags, and web view. That's what was done for the FAQs (which uses a label), I neglected to mention I tried that too.

For some reason, it just shows a blank textview, albeit a large-sized one, as if there's text in it (there isn't any). Strange that copy-pasting works but this doesn't.

Here's my code for it:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    termsTitle.text = "Terms and Conditions"

    htmlContent = "<p style=\"font-family:Helvetica Neue\"><br/><strong><br/> BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA x 12 Pages"

    do {
        let str = try NSAttributedString(data: htmlContent.dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!, options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
        termsTextView.attributedText = str
    } catch {
        print("Dim background error")
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know of any way besides attributed strings, but as for looping through them can you post an example of what text you would want in bold? @zack_falcon

Comment: It sounds like you have the problem that HTML solves

Comment: @Ike10 it's the terms and conditions of our app, so with that wall of text, the titles are usually in bold (General, Copyright, Trademarks, User Guidelines) with paragraphs of text in them along with some bold words in said paragraphs for emphasis such as <Name of the Company>, consent, etc.

Comment: I have to agree with @AaronBrager, HTML seems to be the best solution. I will see if I can find a way to quickly convert what I assume is rich text into HTML.

Comment: @ike10, I actually did that before hand, because that was what was done for the FAQ. The FAQs work, but for some reason Terms and conditions just  shows a giant, blank, but scrollable page. I'll update the question with the code I used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't do this in a Textview without using AttributedString. A possible solution would be using a WebView. Converting your "Terms and Conditions" and "FAQ" to HTML would probably be much easier than using an AttributedString.

Comment: Sorry, I neglected to mention I tried that already. FAQs work. Terms and Conditions doesn't. I posted the code above. Only difference was the length of `htmlContent`. Terms and Conditions is about 12-pages long.

Comment: @zack_falcon you are trying to set HTML to a UITextView. Convert your text to HTML and use a UIWebView instead.

Comment: I added a webview and used the following code: `termsWebView.loadHTMLString(htmlContent, baseURL: nil)` where htmlContent contains the converted text, but it's not displaying anything. Is there more to it than that?

Comment: @zack_falcon htmlContent has to be a valid HTML document including <html> and <body> tags. For example: webView.loadHTMLString("<html><body><p>Hello World!</p></body></html>", baseURL: nil)

Comment: Ah yes, forgot about those. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to use your HTML in a UITextView you can try this function:

```
func getAttributedString(fileName: String) -> NSAttributedString? {
   if let htmlLocation = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(fileName, withExtension: "html"), data = NSData(contentsOfURL: htmlLocation) {
      do {
         let attrString = try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
         return attrString
      } catch let err as NSError {
         print("Attributed String Creation Error")
         print(err.localizedDescription)
         return nil
      }
   } else {
      return nil
   }
}
```

This function assumes you have a `.html` file in your main bundle. You pass it the name (minus extension) of the file (that should be in your project) and then use it like so:

```
textView.attributedText =  getAttributedString("TermsAndConditions")
```

Just to clarify, the textView is a `@IBOutlet` on a View Controller in this example.

This function returns nil if either the `.html` file does not exist or the NSAttributedString conversion failed.

Comment: I tried it this way so I wouldn't have to edit the xib much. However, it displays a long textview, with nothing in it. The HTML file itself works and can be loaded in Chrome. I'm getting no errors either.

Comment: Can you upload the html file somewhere so I can test it myself? @zack_falcon (I understand if you can't)